# GCP Cloud Funtions multi threaded post request

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

So I have this code below, which is spiting a list of ids in x items, then iterates over them and makes a multiple `request.post` to a URL (a google cloud function) but, its only sending the last payload.

```
from threading import Thread
from pprint import pprint
import logging
import requests
import os
import time

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='(%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s',)

def worker(url, payload):
    response = requests.post(url, json=payload)
    pprint(payload)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
    response.raise_for_status()
    pprint(response.content.decode('UTF-8'))

def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from a list."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

secret = 'sometoken'
recovery_url = 'https://some.cloudfuntion.url.here'

ids = [2018345610079096363, 2977875406043034415, 3271712161922849730, 419748955619930226,
       5244962103551406903, 5803235572026782321, 7879812282087191078, 9098437513491289540]

payload = {
    "message": secret,
    "action": "DR",
    "project": 'planar-depth-225211'
}
# LIMIT DR REQUESTS BY A SPECIFIC INT
limits = list(chunks(ids, 4))

for _ids in limits:
    payload.update({"instances": _ids})
    t = Thread(target=worker, args=(recovery_url, payload,))
    t.start()
```

Output:

```
(Thread-1  ) Starting new HTTPS connection (1): xxx.cloudfunctions.net:443
(Thread-2  ) Starting new HTTPS connection (1): xxx.cloudfunctions.net:443
(Thread-2  ) https:xxx.cloudfunctions.net:443 "POST /recovery HTTP/1.1" 200 21
'Recovery with Success' 
'Recovery with Success' 
(Thread-1  ) https://xxx.cloudfunctions.net:443 "POST /recovery HTTP/1.1" 200 21
```

Can I compose the request.post 1st then, execute them?
I don't understand why is only post-ing the last generated payload.
If you check output from line 13, you will see payload has the same content.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using `payload.update()` to mutate the `payload` object, and then passing it through. This is causing the same payload to get used for every thread, because by the time the request is made, the original `payload` has been updated to have the last set of `_ids`.

Instead, create a new `dict` from the existing payload:

```
for _ids in limits:
    t = Thread(target=worker, args=(recovery_url, dict(**payload, instances=_ids)))
    t.start()
```